# PHP Curl post with non-english characters

Tags: php, post, curl, utf-8

I have a small problem with php curl post.

I am trying to post some turkish characters to a forum but aren't posted how it should be.

This is how i save the text:

```
    fwrite($fpp,"\xEF\xBB\xBF");
    fwrite($fpp, $row['template']);
    fclose($fpp);
```

and posting:

```
$this->curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ( $this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->vb_url . 'newthread.php?' . $url_vars );
    curl_setopt ( $this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields );
    curl_setopt ( $this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $this->curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,20);
    curl_setopt ( $this->curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt ( $this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt ( $this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $this->cookie_name );
    curl_setopt ( $this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_name );
    curl_setopt ( $this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_name );
    curl_setopt ( $this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1;    en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
   $result = curl_exec ( $this->curl );
```

this is how it should be:

```
`Bölüm resimleri, dizi indirme ve altyazı linkine aşağıdan ulaşabilirsiniz.`
```

this is how it is posted:

```
`BÃ¶lÃ¼m resimleri, dizi indirme ve altyazÄ± linkine aÅŸaÄŸÄ±dan ulaÅŸabilirsiniz.`
```

Thanks

Comment: spammer? how you got this conclusion? just because i asked help on a php function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with

```
$message = @iconv("UTF-8","Windows-1252//IGNORE",$message);
```

Answer (score 3):

From http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php

Try adding:

```
curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array (
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
));
```

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` suggested by @spencercw

Comment: doesn't work. i get "Your submission could not be processed because a security token was missing."

Comment: I would guess you need a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `text/xml`.

Comment: Does your `$post_fields` variable contain a `securitytoken` entry?

Comment: same with application/x-www-form-urlencoded "Your submission could not be processed because a security token was missing" and yes i have a securitytaken variable whici i take it with curl from the submit page

Comment: I did some looking around about this and one suggestion that I found was to use `url_encode()` on your form post variables.  So, try removing the new `curl_setopt` and use `url_encode` on each of the fields that make up your `$post_fields` variable.

Comment: no luck :( on forum is posted like this: %EF%BB%BF%5Bimg%5Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fi.img