# How to pass a UTF-8 URL to cURL?

Tags: php, curl, utf-8

I have a table in UTF-8 format. I want to read data from the database and then to curl get content. I pass url in UTF-8 format, but I can't get content. what should I do to solve the problem?

I use below code, but had a problem:

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$this->content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What is the error? Do you get any response from curl?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445457/php-curl-post-with-non-english-characters check this related question, this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `utf8_encode` and then `urlencode()` the URL,

```
$url = urlencode(utf8_encode($url));
```

Comment: it doesn't work . when i use this format of url it works:

Comment: lets describe more  when i use this format it dose not work:
$url='http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/563466/تولید-روزانه-۲۳۰-هزار-بدافزار-در-سال-۲۰۱۵';
but when i use this format of url it works:
$url='http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/563466/%D8%AA%D9%88%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%DB%B2%DB%B3%DB%B0-%D9%87%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%84-%DB%B2%DB%B0%DB%B1%DB%B5';

Comment: @masih: try to utf8-encode only the Arabic (?) part of the URL then append that to the main URL, and then try to urlencode the whole thing. Apologies if I got the language name wrong.

Comment: Please don't randomly suggest `utf8_encode`. What is it supposed to fix here?

Comment: @raidenace: thanks to answer . i think best way is the solution you mention. it is persian language:).

Comment: i test the @raidenace solution. i must separate the Persian part of the url and use urlencode ,for example: urlencode('مسیح') and then replace it in the url. but the problem is i don't know how to distinguish utf-8 part of the url??

Comment: i use regex to find utf-8 part and the use urlencode and then replace with preg_replace.so my problem for curl solved